# How to deploy java-play framework web application dist zip file to Local Server

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have created Java-Play framework web Application and follow the deployment steps given on  [Play framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionDist)

For this i have used play 2.0.8 framework and Ubuntu 14.04

- First created Java-play web application
- after created play dist zip file
- then deploy to local server
- unzip the dist zip file
- this dist package contains

  1. start script &
  2. lib folder
- trying to run dist package start script but this file can not run the play application

Please provide me solution or proper tutorial to deploy play dist package and run play web application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- May be u need give permission to start like,

  ```
  sudo chmod 777 start
  ```
- Then run `sudo ./start` from terminal.